# Parametric Data Type

Tags: recursion, types, f#

How do you write a f# recursive data types that define a parametric data

```
type Three <'a>
```

that calls output:

```
Node (1,Node (2,Leaf,Leaf),Node (3,Node (4,Leaf,Leaf),Leaf))
```

if I input:

```
let tree = Node(1, Node(2, Leaf, Leaf), Node(3, Node(4, Leaf, Leaf), Leaf))
tree
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to define a tree. Leaf in your question is called Empty here.

```
type Tree<'a> = Empty | Node of Tree * 'a * Tree
```